# Copying .docx Files From One Directory to Another

Tags: java, file-io, directory, copy, docx

So I was wondering if anyone knew how, or could point me in the direction of some samples that did this in Java? I've tried Googling it, but the examples I find are mostly related to text files.

For example, with this code:

```
// Copies src file to dst file.
// If the dst file does not exist, it is created
void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

It would not work for a .docx file I don't think, right?

So any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help that's offered.

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work for ANY kind of "file."

Comment: Why shouldnt that work for .docx files? The code seems correct to me, it copies the file byte-wise.

Comment: In my experience with conversions, I know formatting can get changed at times. So I was just wondering if anyone had tried this before.

Comment: Why didn't you test this yourself before posting?

Comment: Honestly? A combination of laziness and presumed doubt. My apologies, haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the java.nio package:

```
FileChannel in = new FileInputStream( src ).getChannel();
FileChannel out = new FileOutputStream( dst ).getChannel();
out.transferFrom( in, 0, in.size() );
in.close();
out.close();
```

However both methods should work regardless of the file type of the `File` since they're working with just the bytes. Just go ahead give it a go.

Comment: Are you sure that's right? I'm trying to mess with it in my program and Eclipse tells me to change the type of `in` from FileInputStream to FileChannel?

Comment: Sorry yes that was a typo, change `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` to `FileChannel`.

Answer (score 0):

Copying it character by character (8-bits) works fine.

```
void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    int c;
    while ((c = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(c);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use File.Copy or File.Directory, Something like this

```
 var oldfile = "C\\folder";
 var Newfile = "C\\Newfolder";

if(File.Exsit(NewFile)){
File.Copy(oldfile, Newfile);
Message.Show("Yourmessage");
}
else{
Message.Show("If it fails");
}
```

I added the If statements to make sure it works